# all(map) and any(map) output boolean in Python, but truthy map object in IPython

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, any, shadowing

I'm using python 3.10.1, interactively through ipython (7.31.0, calling the same python 3.10.1) for exploration, and then directly through python once my scripts are ready.

I had a bug in my code which I reduced to the following difference in behavior between the two:

[IPython]

```
In [1]: any(map(bool, ("")))
Out[1]: <map at 0x7f7f2d6061d0>
```

[CPython]

```
>>> any(map(bool, ("")))
False
```

Because the output `map` object in IPython is truthy, when using the code in an `if` statement the two programs will give opposite results. I'd like to know what's causing this difference, if there is anything I can do to fix it, and if there are other bugs (features?) like it that I should be aware of.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. ipython on my machine and at https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/ both returned False.

Comment: In IPython, what does `any` evaluate to? Do you see `<built-in function any>`, or something else? What is the result of `import sys; sys.version` in each environment?

Comment: You've done `from numpy import *` or something like that in your IPython session. Don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check `any.__module__`.  It should say `'builtins'`. If it doesn't, then execute `del any`.

This symptom usually means you have shadowed the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with numpy's function of the same name:

```
>>> any(map(bool, ("")))
False
>>> from numpy import any
>>> any(map(bool, ("")))
<map object at 0x7ffff6874a90>
```

[IPython will do this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all) if you've started it in `--pylab` mode, or enabled that with the `%pylab` magic.

Comment: "IPython will do this if you've started it in --pylab mode." - an automatic star import? Whose idea was that?

Comment: I don't know the history. Probably some poor scientist who's been receiving hate mail about it from developers for over 10 years

Comment: `--InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=False` turns off the star import

Comment: The builtin `any` works with a `generator` input, the `np.any` requires an expanded generator, `list(map(...))`.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed calling `numpy.any` and it was exactly because of `--pylab` mode